# i need to insert latitude and longitude in database from click event but when i click i got zero values in database not an actual values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

Using ASP.net and WebForms i am trying to store the user's location (Latitude, Longitude) to a database. This presents the problem:

i want to get values of laqngitude and latude of google map by clicking Bbutton i got 0 values in database..
my database ha two filed langitude and latitude which has double datatype.

Here's the sample code of my first attempt:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
   <head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var long = 0;
       var lat = 0;
       window.onload = function () {
           var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.9300, 72.8200),
               zoom: 14,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
               long = e.latLng.lng();
               lat = e.latLng.lat();
               document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
               document.getElementById("lng").value = long;
               alert("Latitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " + long);
           });
       }
   </script>

<form id="myForm" runat="server">
   <div id="dvMap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
   </div>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lat" runat="server" />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lng" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

</form>
</body>
```

And below is the .aspx code-behind file. We save the longitude and latitude to the database during the Click event of the button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Ask Stackoverflow how to get these values from browser-land javascript
        Double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat.Value);
        Double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lng.Value);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "@Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        string query1 = "insert into Courses(longi,lati) values (@lati, @longi)";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lati", latitude);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longi", longitude);

        con.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the form being posted in your server side code. The Request.Form object to be more precise.

There is a NameValueCollection property on the form where you can lookup your posted form values with string key lookups

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string lat,lng; 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["lat"])) { 
    lat = nvc["lat"];
 } 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["lng"])) { 
    lng = nvc["lng"]; 
}
```